# SetCustomUI for Custom Ribbon Error: Object Required

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to tell MS Access to load a custom ribbon when the database opens. In my struggle to get this to work, I have resorted to copying EXACTLY the examples I have found online, using their generic XML, variable names, etc. No matter what I do, the ActiveProject.SetCustomUI line throws an error, "Object Required", highlighting the string variable that holds the xml.

Why would this be looking for an object? Firstly, the documentation shows this parameter should be a String, but also every example I can find online does the same.

Because I know someone will ask for it:

```
Public Function LoadRibbon()
Dim customUiXml As String

    customUiXml = "<mso:customUI xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & _
         "<mso:ribbon><mso:tabs><mso:tab id=""myTab"" label=""New Tab"" " & _
         "insertBeforeQ=""mso:TabView"">" & _
         "<mso:group id=""group1"" label=""New Group"">" & _
         "<mso:button id=""button1"" label=""Test Button"" size=""large"" " & _
         "imageMso=""GetExternalDataFromText"" />" & _
         "</mso:group></mso:tab></mso:tabs></mso:ribbon></mso:customUI>"

    ActiveProject.SetCustomUI (customUiXml) 'highlights "customUiXml" with the error

End Function
```

I call LoadRibbon() from the Form_Load event.

The above code is pretty much just copy/paste from an online example, but still gives me the same issues I had when I tried anything else.  What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show link of online example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveProject` is MS Project VBA, not Access VBA.

You can try using `Application.LoadCustomUI` to load custom UI elements:

```
Application.LoadCustomUI "MyUI", customUiXml
```

Comment: Well, that cleared up the error, certainly, thank you! Only problem now is it still doesn't load (or at least change) the ribbon.  Onward...